# Apache Beam Java SDK SparkRunner write to parquet error

Tags: apache-beam, parquet, apache-beam-io

I'm using Apache Beam with Java.
I'm trying to read a csv file and write it to parquet format using the SparkRunner on a predeployed Spark env, using local mode.
Everything worked fine with the DirectRunner, but the SparkRunner simply wont work.
I'm using maven shade plugin to build a fat jat.

Code is as below:

Java:

```
public class ImportCSVToParquet{
-- ommitted
                File csv = new File(filePath);
                PCollection<String> vals = pipeline.apply(TextIO.read().from(filePath));

                String parquetFilename = csv.getName().replaceFirst("csv", "parquet");
                String outputLocation = FolderConventions.getRawFilePath(confETL.getHdfsRoot(), parquetFilename);

                PCollection<GenericRecord> processed = vals.apply(ParDo.of(new ProcessFiles.GenericRecordFromCsvFn()))
                        .setCoder(AvroCoder.of(new Config().getTransactionSchema()));

                LOG.info("Processed file will be written to: " + outputLocation);
                processed.apply(FileIO.<GenericRecord>write().via(ParquetIO.sink(conf.getTransactionSchema())).to(outputLocation));


        pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();


}
```

POM dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-spark</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-parquet</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
/dependencies>
```

Spark script:

```
spark-submit \
--class package.ImportCSVToParquet \
--master local[*] \
--executor-cores 2 \
--executor-memory 2g \
--driver-memory 2g \
--driver-cores 2 \
--conf spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage=false \
--conf spark.wholeStage.codegen=false \
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=2005 \
--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=2g \
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=4048 \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35" \
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.io.tmpdir=/path-to-tmp/" \
--conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=./" \
--jars path-to-jar \
/path-to-jar "$@"
```

I get the following error:

```
2019-08-07 13:37:49 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3)
org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter$Builder.<init>(Lorg/apache/parquet/io/OutputFile;)V
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:34)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteUnshardedTempFilesFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:214)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:176)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.DoFnRunnerWithMetrics.processElement(DoFnRunnerWithMetrics.java:65)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.SparkProcessContext$ProcCtxtIterator.computeNext(SparkProcessContext.java:137)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v20_0.com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:145)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v20_0.com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:140)
        at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1038)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:969)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:760)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:344)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter$Builder.<init>(Lorg/apache/parquet/io/OutputFile;)V
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter$Builder.<init>(AvroParquetWriter.java:162)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter$Builder.<init>(AvroParquetWriter.java:153)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter.builder(AvroParquetWriter.java:43)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.parquet.ParquetIO$Sink.open(ParquetIO.java:304)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileIO$Write$ViaFileBasedSink$1$1.prepareWrite(FileIO.java:1359)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink$Writer.open(FileBasedSink.java:937)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteUnshardedTempFilesFn.processElement(WriteFiles.java:533)
```

It seems that the job does the reading and transformations, but fails when tries to write to the filesystem. I'm not using HDFS at the moment. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am certain that the ParquetIO depends on the Parquet 1.10+ release, which added a "hadoop-neutral" API to the parquet file readers/writers.

Spark 2.2.3 [depends on](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11/2.2.3) Parquet 1.8.2, which does not have the builder(...) constructor that the Beam ParquetIO uses, which is confirmed by the exception.

If possible, the simplest solution would be to update to Spark 2.4 which has bumped the Parquet version to 1.10.0.

If you can't upgrade Spark versions, there are a couple of techniques for overriding the jars brought in by Spark:

1. You can set `spark.(driver|executor).userClassPathFirst` to `true`, which will place the classes in your fat jar before the jars provided by spark. This might work, or it might introduce new dependency conflicts.
2. You can try replacing the `parquet-xx-1.8.2.jar` in your local spark installation with `parquet-xx-1.10.0` (assuming that they are drop-in replacements).  If this works, you can apply the same strategy to a spark job in a cluster by setting the `spark.yarn.jars` property when submitting the job.
3. You can try shading the beam ParquetIO and its parquet dependencies in your fat jar.

**Edit**: This is a known issue [BEAM-5164](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-5164).

**Edit (workaround)**:

I managed to get this to work for Spark 2.2.3 by following the [instructions](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/) with some modifications:

- I used the scala 2.11 dependencies and set them to `<scope>provided</scope>` (probably optional).
- I added the following three locations to the `maven-shade-plugin`:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
          <filters>

... unchanged ...

          </filters>
          <relocations>
            <relocation>
              <pattern>org.apache.parquet</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>shaded.org.apache.parquet</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
            <!-- Some packages are shaded already, and on the original spark classpath. Shade them more. -->
            <relocation>
              <pattern>shaded.parquet</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>reshaded.parquet</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
            <relocation>
              <pattern>org.apache.avro</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>shaded.org.apache.avro</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
          </relocations>
        </configuration>
        <executions>

... unchanged ...

        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Ryan thanks for pointing this out, this was the issue indeed!
I've tried your suggestion no 1 but it produced new deps conflicts.
The second approach is working fine, but I don't like that I'm messing with the Spark 2.2.3 jars, and deploying jars manually in the spark config.
Can you please elaborate suggestion 3? I already shade all the dependency jars while building the fatjar.

Comment: I admit I didn't succeed in getting option 3 to work!  I was following the fat jar instructions at https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/

Ideally, you would include relocation instructions for org.apache.parquet, and "rewrite" all of those clases to "shaded.org.apache.parquet"  (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html).

That way, the parquet classes used would no longer be in conflict wih the spark ones ahead in the classpath.

Comment: I added the JIRA issue for tracking... this might be a regression.  I'll give it a try with Beam 2.13.0 artifacts.

Comment: I've tried with Beam version 2.12 artifacts, but it was spawning the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst` and `spark.executor.userClassPathFirst` as it's stil experimental. But intstead, use `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath`.

Definition from the official [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/configuration.html) : "Extra classpath entries to prepend to the classpath of the driver."

- "prepend", as in, put in front of Spark’s core classpath.

Example :

> --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=C:\Users\Khalid\Documents\Projects\libs\jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Khalid\Documents\Projects\libs\jackson-core-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Khalid\Documents\Projects\libs\jackson-databind-2.6.0.jar

This solved my problem (conflict between the version of Jackson i want to use, and the one spark is using).

Hope it helps.