# Flatting two Generic Records into one and write it to parquet file

Tags: java, apache-beam

In global, the idea is to read a parquet file (that return PCollection) make new PCollection depending on the file that we have read, merge those two PCollections into one and write it into parquet file on some other location.

I am trying this code on SparkRunner.

I can't post the full code, but I will try to point the logic.

This is a code snippet:

```
PCollection<GenericRecord> oldGen = pipeline.apply(ParquetIO.read(SCHEMA).from(/path);
PCollection<GenericRecord> newGen = processNew(); //in this part I am making new PCollection
PCollectionList<GenericRecord> pList = PCollectionList.of(oldGen).and(newGen);

pList
     .apply(Flatten.pCollections())
     .setCoder(AvroCoder.of(GenericRecord.class, SCHEMA))
     .apply(FileIO.<GenericRecord>write()
         .via(ParquetIO.sink(SCHEMA)).to(/outputlocation));
```

When I check the output location I am getting only one PCollection of those two that should be flattened (no rules which one).
I've tried to make some prints after flatting collections and the print looks fine, also I've tried to write those data into .txt format and that works fine too.

Also, I've tried one silly solution, and to my surprise, it passed somehow.
The oldGen parameter has one column with a boolean flag. I've transformed that pcollection into two collections, one with a flag true, and the other one with a flag false.

Snippet for PCollectionList looks like this:

```
PCollectionList<GenericRecord> pList = PCollectionList.of(newGen).and(trueGen).and(falseGen);
```

Writing to parquet looks the same as in the previous snippet, but with this snippet, I am getting a good parquet file with all necessary records.

It looks really strange because in both situations I am getting the same PCollection when I flat those PCollections, and one more thing when I run it on DirectRunner everything works fine without any issues.

The Beam version is 2.14.0, and Spark version is 2.2.3.

Does anyone have an idea why is this happening in the first case?

Comment: I agree, very strange!  Just to confirm -- in the given example *all* of the `GenericRecord` instances have the same `SCHEMA`?  Can you give us the Beam version and Spark version?

Comment: @RyanSkraba yeah it's the same SCHEMA. I just updated the question with versions of Beam and Spark..

Comment: @RyanSkraba this version of spark is not compatible with this version of beam, so parquet and avro dependencies need to be shaded. Can this be the source of this issue?

Comment: Good point @IvanMilasevic!  There's some documentation on running ParquetIO and older versions of Spark at https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/parquet/ .  Are you using this technique?  I'm not sure this is related, since the "boolean flag" simplified example should also fail if it was a shading problem!

Comment: @RyanSkraba yes we are using that technique. Maven contains the snippet that you posted as an answer on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57395634/apache-beam-java-sdk-sparkrunner-write-to-parquet-error . We didn't have any issues with the parquet format after using the snippet from the link except this one.